# Using DesktopCouch without Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, couchdb, desktopcouch

I want to know if it is possible to use DesktopCouch without UbuntuOne, but with a local CouchDB Server. I found a pairing Tool, but this crashes, when I try to pair two computer.

I can find the local Desktop Couches with the Avahi Zeroconf Browser and it should be possible to find them with Python and start a replication

To make a long story short: I want to sync DesktopCouch Databases in my local network without Ubuntu One. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hm. This is precisely and absolutely what the desktopcouch pairing tool is for, so if it's crashing it sounds like you've found a bug. Can you file a bug about this issue, and we'll look into it?

Comment: Hm, I run Ubuntu 10.10 and I'm using the Ubuntu One Nightlies PPA, DesktopCouch Version 1.0.6+r267~maverick1. Maybe a Problem with 10.10. But I don't want to use the pairing tool. I want to use a Python Script

Comment: OK. The pairing tool is written in Python; what it does is find other desktopcouches on the network (with zeroconf), and then set up pairing records at each end for those two desktopcouches. So that should help you get started!

Answer (score 0):

Desktopcouch use couchdb as base then you que use couchdb replication

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/replication.html

You can use futon ('web' interface)

http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/tour.html#replication

Your own futon address:

```
$HOME/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html
```

or

```
file:///home/{username}/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html
```

[Source](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch/).